# Orange Pi stack site

Tags: discussion

Will the Stack Overflow launch at some moment Orange Pi questions site, similar to Raspberry Pi? I've tried po pose my question about Orange Pi on the Rpi site, and it appeared to be offtopic. It would be nice if Stack can support Orange Pi as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are more than welcome to *suggest* such a Stack Exchange site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), our site for suggesting new Stack Exchange sites (this is how the Raspberry Pi site got started too).

I see no such proposal at the moment, so you will need to suggest it.

Once you suggest it, you will need to get enough followers for it if it is to become a beta site. I suggest reading the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) of Area 51 to understand the process.

Comment: Thank you, I have posted a proposal.